# Python 3.5: Tarfile append mode "ReadError" on empty tar

Tags: python-3.x, tarfile

I have encountered a problem working with the creation of new tarfiles using the latest python 3.5 package and its `tarfile` module. This problem is similar to those discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28361665/how-to-append-a-file-to-a-tar-file-use-python-tarfile-module) and [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue6123). In the former case the suggested solution returns the error `ReadError: empty header`, and in the latter case it's a closed issue from eight years ago, the patch for which should already have been applied by loading the latest version of the language. The docs for the Tarfile module explicitly state that "a" can be used to create new tarfiles.

The issue specifically arises in the case of attempting to create a new tarfile. The code that generates it is replicated in full below; a simple script I was using to benchmark the task in multiprocessing.

```
#just a little script to test copy times for a control

import os
import os.path
import time
import shutil
import multiprocessing
import tarfile

global source; source = "/home/patches/Documents/Scripting Projects/Resources/Test Payload"
global dest; dest = "/home/patches/Desktop/Copy Benchmark 
Output.tar.bz2"
global start
global end
global diff
global testing; testing = True
global numConsumers; numConsumers = multiprocessing.cpu_count()


#Classes!
class copyProc(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, qTask):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.qTask = qTask
        os.chdir(source)

    def run(self):
        proc_name = self.name
        while True:
            next_task = self.qTask.get()
            if next_task is None:
                # Poison pill means shutdown
                print('%s: Exiting' % proc_name)
                self.qTask.task_done()
                break
            next_task()
            self.qTask.task_done()
        return

class copyJob(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.tgt = a
    def __call__(self):
        tar = tarfile.open(dest, "a")
        tar.add(self.tgt)
        tar.close()

#Function
def announce():
    print("Starting copy benchmark - multiprocessing.")
    foo = input("Press any key to begin")

def startTimer():
    global start
    start = time.time()


def setup():
    os.chdir(source)
    for a, b, files in os.walk(source):
        for file in files:
        tasks.put(copyJob(file))
    for i in range(numConsumers):
        tasks.put(None)

def endTimer():
    global end
    end = time.time()

def prompt():
    diff = end - start
#   os.remove(dest)
    print("The test took %s seconds" % str(diff))
    bar = input("Run again? Y/n")
    if bar == "n":
        testing = False

#runtime
if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn")
    tasks = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
    announce()
    startTimer()
    setup()
consumers = []
for i in range(numConsumers):
    consumers.append(copyProc(tasks))
for w in consumers:
    w.start()
tasks.join()
endTimer()
prompt()
```

Edit to add: the problem specifically is that, instead of the specific behaviour, the script instead throws a "ReadError: empty header" exception on attempting to open the tarfile.

Comment: and the problem is?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, being clear on that would have helped. I've since amended the question. The specific problem is right at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out, the issue was that having multiple processes trying to open the file more or less simultaneously was causing the issue. The solution is to use some form of locking to prevent this.

In my case, I used a simple multiprocessing.Lock() object and had the processes acquire it before appending and release it afterward. This solution was still faster than performing all the appends in a single process. Not sure why.

I hope if, like me, you had this problem, that this solution works for you as well.